# How can I include custom variables in AMP analytics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, amp-html

A few months ago we introduced AMP to our Rails application. Our implementation includes the following:

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "vars": {
      "account": <%= ga.profile_code.inspect.html_safe %>
    },
    "triggers": {
      "trackPageview": {
        "on": "visible",
        "request": "pageview"
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

However, we now realise that we are missing some important custom variables that are used in the Google Analytics script for our non-AMP pages. These are set within a script as follows (where `_gaq` is an array):

```
  <% ga.variables.each do |vars| %>
    _gaq.push([ '_setCustomVar', <%= vars[:placement] %>, '<%= vars[:label] %>', '<%= vars[:variable] %>', <%= vars[:scope_number] %> ]);
  <% end %>
```

Is it possible in AMP Analytics to set custom variables without any restriction on the variable names? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You should notice that [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) are only available for legacy google analytics tracking. For the latest implementation, you will need to replace your custom variables with custom dimensions instead. You could check the migration guide [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/) and [Here](https://misterphilip.com/universal-analytics/migration/variables).

After you have made a migration, you can check the [implementation of sending custom dimensions and custom metrics in AMP page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/#extending-ga).

> For example, you can send a custom dimension with a pageview by
>   including the Custom Dimension parameter (or any other parameters you
>   want to include with the hit) in the **extraUrlParams section**. This
>   section can be included at the trigger level for single requests or at
>   a global level to send the data with all requests.

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
  },
  "extraUrlParams": {
    "cd3": "AMP"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageviewWithCustomData": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    },
    "trackEvent" : {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "ui-components",
        "eventAction": "header-click"
      },
      "extraUrlParams": {
        "ni": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. We'll give that a try.